# Difference between char** and char*

Tags: c++, pointers, multidimensional-array

So I have a 2D array (I think) in my main:
`char* map[width][height] = {MATRIX HERE};`

And I'm passing it to a function:
`bool canAccessEdge (char** map, int size, int currentPosX, int currentPosY);`

I'm passing with with via:
`canAccessEdge (*map, 10, playerStartPosX, playerStartPosY);`

I want to traverse the map array and mark the positions that the player was already on. But I understand I can't change a value at an index in the function.
I understand that `char map [][]` would be an array and `char *map` is a pointer. So what is `char* map [][]`? Is there a work around without changing the prototype?
Sorry if these are dumb questions... I can't grasp pointers/arrays too well.

```
bool exitPossible (char** map, int size, int currentPosX, int currentPosY) {
    ...
    *maze[currentPosX][currentPosY] = "V"; // Operand of '*' must be a pointer but has type "char"
    (&maze)[currentPosX][currentPosY] = "V"; // Changes whole row and not the right position
    &(maze)[currentPosX][currentPosY] = "V"; // Expression must be a modifiable lvalue (I assume it's immutable)
    ...
}
```

Comment: If your native 2D array map really is declared to store non-const pointers to terminated strings as elements, and you really can't change the prototype argument `char** map`, then you're screwed, because those aren't anywhere near equivalent. I surmise the *real* assignment was to store single *characters*, not strings, in a `char map[width][height]`, at which point this becomes trivial, but that's pure speculation and wild-guessing.

Comment: You tagged it as c++, I'd suggest a c++ way. Use a reference to array parameter type. `bool exitPossible(char*(&map)[width][height], ...)`. `width` `height` are both constant values or expressions of course.

Comment: declared map is actually an array of pointers. So there is a question: what exactly is "MATRIX HERE"?

Comment: `char*` can be a pointer to a char, *or* a pointer to an array of char.  `char**` can be a pointer to a pointer to a char, *or* a pointer to an array of pointers to a char, *or* a pointer to a pointer to an array of char, *or* a pointer to an array of pointers to array of char.

Answer (score 3):

`char[N]` can degrade to `char*`. That does **not** mean that `char[N][M]` can degrade to `char**`. Beginners always make this assumption but it is not true.

`char*[N][M]` is something else again. That is not a 2D array of `char` (which seems to be what you want). A 2D array of chars is `char[N][M]`. With a 2D array of chars the correct syntax is

```
maze[currentPosX][currentPosY] = 'V';
```

Note the single quotes.

If you want to pass a 2D array of chars to a function then the simplest way is to declare the function with a 2D array of chars

```
bool exitPossible(char maze[N][M], ...)
```

but the reality is that `maze` here is a pointer to a 1D array, it's actually not possible to have an array as a function parameter in C++. So the truthful declaration of the function is

```
bool exitPossible(char (*maze)[M], ...)
```

Here we see what `maze` really is, a pointer to a 1D array (of size M). And this completes the first paragraph above. A 2D array `char[N][M]` degrades not to `char**` but to `char (*)[M]`. If this seems complicated then you are right, a good book is needed to explain it fully.

Note that in all this discussion `N` and `M` are **constants**. In C++ array sizes cannot be variable.

Comment: `:%s/degrade/decay/g`

Comment: What does it mean the OP question "Is there a work around without changing the prototype?"?

Comment: @KonstantinL The prototype says `char**`. There is no way to pass a 2D array to a function prototyped `char**`, the two types are fundamentally different.